# Showing hidden section of lengthy text by clicking link

Tags: javascript

I have a review box on my website with 10 long reviews. I want to shorten "each" one and then put a "Read More" link. When people click each link it will uncover more text for that specific review. This is a very common concept on the Internet. I don't care if the text can be hidden again, along as it can be shown. I know I need a separate ID for each hidden review. I have code that opens one review, but of course when you click for the next review nothing happens. So, I need the total JavaScript code from top to bottom that will open each review separately as they get clicked. I am not fluent in JavaScript coding so any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code that seems to work for one review: If you can improve it, great, but I really need to add to it so all the other ID's work as well. I have "show" as the id for my clickable link, and "content" is the id for the hidden text. I was thinking that the other id's would just follow as 'show2, show3, etc" and then "content2, content3, etc"

```
function showHideP(Id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById('content');
    if (obj) {
        obj.style.display = 'block';
    }
    var obj = document.getElementById('show');
    if (obj) {
        obj.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well, or even better create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: From the look of your code, you're not using the `Id` argument at all. You're always selecting by `id = "content"` and `id = "show"`.  Perhaps if your elements are `<div id="content59">...</div>` then you'd want to do `getElementById('content' + Id);`?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need `id`'s. all you need is to send the element in the onclick function using `onclick="myFunction(this)"`.  using the parameter `this` (the element that was clicked on) you can find show the "more content" by using `element.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block` (depending on how the page is structured, you may need to use different ways of traversing the DOM tree to find the element you want to show).

```js
function showReadMore(element) {
    element.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
    element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.moreContent {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="reivewSection">
    <div class="review">
        Review 1 
        <a class="readmore" onclick="showReadMore(this)" href="#">Read More...</a>        
        <div class="moreContent">
            This is more Content for Review 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="review">
        Review 2
        <a class="readmore" onclick="showReadMore(this)" href="#">Read More...</a>
        <div class="moreContent">
            This is more Content for Review 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="review">
        Review 3
        <a class="readmore" onclick="showReadMore(this)" href="#">Read More...</a>
        <div class="moreContent">
            This is more Content for Review 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="review">
        Review 4
        <a class="readmore" onclick="showReadMore(this)" href="#">Read More...</a>
        <div class="moreContent">
            This is more Content for Review 4
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>    
</div>
```

Comment: Okay this seems to work... two things.... does "this" need to be replaced with something, or do I keep it as is? And, is there a way to click "Read More" and have "Read More" disappear when the rest of the content replaces it?  Thanks so much...

Comment: `this` should be kept as is. it means "send this element to the function as a parameter" so that the function does not have to find the element clicked by ids or classes. and yes to the hiding of "Read More". you need to add `element.style.display = 'none';` in your function (i edited above so you can check it out)

Comment: Thanks very much indubitablee... This solution is working very well. I did need to add a "return false;" in the onclick section so the page wouldn't jump to the top. All the reviews open nicely now. I added a bit of css to each div section and it's aligned and looking good. Great idea... thanks again!

Comment: @nairb00, it jumps to the top of the page because of the `href="#"` but you can cut that part out. i just did that for aesthetics because when an `<a>` has an `href` attribute, the text color is blue and it underlines on hover etc. but return false works too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something similar to what you want. For this to work, in the example below,I have added a "view-detail" class on all "readmore" anchor tags, make sure the readmore links are assigned unique href links(ids of those divs that have the full content), for example the first readmore href's link would be href="show1", for second element the href would be "show2" and so on. Also these same hrefs should be assigned to all the content divs as Ids. For example the first content div id will be "show1" and so one. This way you can use "this" keyword to display the content on mouse click. Heres a jquery snippet used to display the content of clicked element in a Jquery UI popup, you can ignore the code of dialog & replace it with display:block,display:none as per your need. :

```
   $( document ).on( "click", "a.view-detail", function() {
            var hrefId= $(this).attr('href');
            //console.log(hrefId);

            $( "#dialog-message" ).html($(hrefId).html());

        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
        });

            //$(hrefId).toggle();
        });
```